# MySQL Connector .NET & Unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode, mysql-connector

I am having some serious issues trying to get MySql Connector for .NET to insert unicode text into the database. I have read so many forums on this and none of the fixes seems to work. I have tried all fo the following and various combinations thereof:

```
- Append ;charset=utf8 to connection string
- Append ;character set=utf8 to connection string
- Use 'N' prefix (although, I believe this is for MsSql only, but was worth a try)
- Set utf8 collations for database, table and columns
- Issue this command: SET NAMES UTF8
- Issue this command: SET CHARACTER SET UTF8
- Tried both Direct ad-hoc query and MySqlParameter as ways to insert
```

I am using MySqlConnector 6.4.3 and no matter what I do, I cannot get this wretched thing to work. I'm about to lose my mind...

Anyone had a similar issue and fixed it??

Many thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: `; CharSet=utf8` on the connection string combined with a UTF-8 collation on columns totally covers it for me. Can you give some example that fails? Is it possible your characters are getting mangled before they hit the database? How are they being mistreated?

Comment: @bobince If you add that comment as an actual reply I'll upvote you. This totally solved it for me